# How to make SVN perform a command without making changes

Tags: svn

In CVS I could do the following

```
cvs -n update
```

And it would should me what would happen if I ran an update but without changing anything. I mainly use this to check if I am going to get a lot of conflicts.

In svn I would like to do the same but with the switch command

ie:

```
svn -n switch url1 url2
```

My understanding is that there is a --dry-run switch which goes through the motions but doesn't actually give any output. So it is half of the way there :)

How can I get it to do a dry run **and** show what the results would be (which files will be Modified, which Updated, Deleted, Added and Conflicting).

Thanks

Update:
Regarding those who have suggested I use --dry-run I have tried the following

> svn switch url --dry-run

and I get

```
Subcommand 'switch' doesn't accept option '--dry-run'
```

In theory it sounds good but it doesn't seem to work, am I doing something wrong?

Comment: I don't understand why you think svn switch would be equivalent to cvs update? It's not.

Comment: I know the switch in svn is different from update cvs . That pretty obvious. The question. In CVS, we can use the -n option with any cvs command. What is the equivalent for svn, I would like to use it with switch?

Comment: Why would you want to dry-run with a switch? Check Don's answer, I think `merge` might be what your are looking for.

Comment: I don't understand your question.... I want to do a switch and I want to know what the impact will be in terms of Conflicts, Additions, Updates etc... What is so strange about that?

Comment: @hhafez Well the answer is --dry-run IS the option for svn. That it does not work with switch is tough luck, but Don already gave you a workaround, so be happy ;-)

Comment: I find it strange that it works with some but not all svn commands thats not what I would call consistent behavior, but you make a valid point and the workaround will just have to do for now.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Use `merge` and `--dry-run` with the same URLs you will use for the `switch`. It should give you the information you are looking for even though you'll be using `switch` instead of `merge` in the end.

Comment: @MikeMiller If you want to check what file will be committed, don't write a message with the command. This way an editor will open for you to introduce the message and the list of files that are about to be committed will show up

Comment: Adding --dry-run to a commit would be very useful, as the output (list of files) could be piped to other commands (eg a list of changed files for uploading to a web site so they can be previewed BEFORE to "real" svn ci is done).

Answer (score 10):

On svn update, you can use `svn status --show-updates` to show all items you will update.

For merges, you can use `--dry-run` any problems.

Answer (score 3):

Use *--dry-run*

> --dry-run
>   Goes through all the motions of running a command, but makes no actual changes—either on disk or in the repository.

From: [Subversion Complete Reference](http://svnbook.red-bean.com/en/1.1/ch09.html)

Well your question was (and still is so far)

> How to make SVN perform a command without making changes

The answer is: **Use *--dry-run***

The fact the *--dry-run* does not work with the *switch* command is tough luck, but @Don gave you a nice workaround

> Use merge and --dry-run with the same URLs you will use for the switch. It should give you the information you are looking for even though you'll be using switch instead of merge in the end.

Of course you can also file a [bug/enhancement report with subversion](http://subversion.tigris.org/issue-tracker.html).

Comment: @hhafez Please read the reference guide. --dry-run may not apply to all svn commands, but most (switch is obviously an exception)

Comment: @lothar Unfortunately, `commit` is an exception, too.

Comment: And checkout.  In fact, the statement "--dry-run may not apply to all svn commands, but most" appears to be simply wrong.

Answer (score 0):

As far as I was aware, `dry-run` will show you what it will do, including what will be conflicted, etc.

http://svnbook.red-bean.com/en/1.4/svn.branchmerge.copychanges.html (search for "dry-run" on that page)

Answer (score 0):

In addition to svn status -u, which will show what files will get updated.
This oneliner will give you output about what contents will be changed :

`svn diff -r BASE:HEAD`

You might want to pipe this to more if it are many changes.

`svn diff -r BASE:HEAD | more`